Fairest way to share gifts between kids
I want to give to 3 kids the possibility to choose 2 gifts each, out of a total of 10 gifts. All gifts are of exactly the same value.  You can think of them as all being frisbees (or whatever) but with different colors and patterns on each one, making them unique.
Major and only requirement is to make the process as equal and fair as possible without having disgruntled kids (this right here, makes the task impossible, I know).
In an ideal world, the preferences of the kids would NOT collide on which is the "best" frisbee to get first and which is the second one, but you cannot count that there will not be any arguing.
A simple/naive solution would be to throw all frisbees in an opaque black plastic garbage bag, and have them in sequence pull one out without looking.  But then you have issues of who goes first, etc, and you are completely preventing them of somehow choosing their favorites.
The best I could come up with was to give each kid an equal number of markers/tokens and have them secretly allocate tokens on their preferred choices.  Then, given the number of tokens on each frisbee you allocate them to whoever "paid" more.
But you still run into edge cases where a number of kids allocated the same number of tokens on the same item, and I cannot come up with a clear set of rules of how to clarify these edges cases.
Is there a "foolproof" way that makes this process as automated and "fair" as possible?
Not sure how to express the whole situation on clearly mathematical terms, but I am betting that this should belong to a an already existing family of similar mathematical puzzles.
Thanks!
EDIT:
Just came up with another "solution":

You ask them to secretly rate each frisbee from best/"most desirable" to worst/"least desirable"

Then each one reads their first entry. For choices that they are unique, each one gets their item.  For collisions, nobody gets anything.

You move to item number 2 and repeat with the same rules.

As soon as a kid has two frisbees they drop out.


This might also work out nicely that if there is a much coveted frisbee, NOBODY gets it and you save yourself from post-sharing whining of: "Bu-bu-bu-but I really wanted that one, and now SHE got it..."
Regardless, still looking for an more "mathematical" solution, if one exists....

How do you define fair?  A natural approach is to assign numbers at random and let them choose in order 1,2,3,3,2,1

Fair as in from the perspective of each kid.  Avoiding situations where one chooses before the other, or any ways that you might be blamed that the procedure was not, well, "fair" to each kid.  Experience with kids is required in order to properly define fair, I am afraid...  In your example, for example, kid number three would be already crying by the time their turn comes to pick up their item...  I now understand that my question might NOT have a proper "mathematical" answer if we have to comply with the kids imaginary world... :(

I suggest using coin flips (et al) to break ties.

I think you are trying to achieve two separate things: (A) no child has an advantage over any other; and (B) so far as possible they each get what they want. You haven't specified which of these is more important so you are struggling to design a mechanism which achieves both. It's easy to achieve (A): just distribute the gifts at random. It's easy to achieve (B): just let them pick in turn. I don;t think there can be a perfect outcome for both (A) and (B): what do you want to happen if they all want the same gift and don't at all care about the others?

Without fully specified criteria this isn't quite a mathematical question, but I think a combination of the token / bidding setup you suggest, together with coin flips to break ties as user2661923 suggests, ought to be an okay compromise between the two criteria Blitzer uses.

I happened to be faced with an analogous problem in actuality, with the following differences

The people were grown-ups with some background in Operations Research

We first had to agree upon some criterion, and after much discussion, it was agreed that each person would secretly  rate each object as to its desirabiity on a scale of $1-10$, and we would work out optimal assignment(s) based on the criterion of maximum $\;$ total $\;$ satisfaction for the group as a whole, and in case more than one assignment gave the highest satisfaction, one of them would be randomly chosen.

We used the Hungarian algorithm and arrived at an amicable solution, although people obviously didn't get all their favourite choices



The key factor was to first get people to agree to a distribution method that was perceived to be fair

A recent event in tennis demonstrates how the perception of fairness is more important than fairness.
The French Open is the only Grand Slam event that doesn't use a Hawk Eye to adjudge line calls, in disputes the referee comes down  from her chair, inspects the mark and makes a judgment. Sometimes they also show Hawk Eye assessment, but the final decision is the referee's.
So in the finals, Zverev disputed a service called in, the referee adjudged it as in, but the Hawk Eye showed it to be out by $2mm$. Now the Hawkeye has a margin of error around that, so the referee stuck to his decision, and Zverev was upset and peeved.
The point I am making is that the French Open way of physically examining the ball mark (supposedly with no margin of error!) is often disputed in close cases, (although reluctantly accepted) whereas the Hawk Eye judgement (with a known small margin of error) is never disputed, you can't argue with a machine ! Fairness lies in the eye of the beholder !
I hope I have given you some ideas !

Very interesting usecase and proposed solution (as well as the tennis trivia, too), thanks!

@stratosgear: You are welcome !
